# typescript typesafety for generic graph-like data-structure class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, type-safety

I was trying to implement a graph-like data structure in typescript and was type safing it, with difficulty, after many solutions I arrived at this:

```
interface Cities {
  lisbon: any
  porto: any
  faro: any
}

class Graph<T> {
  adjacencyList: {
    [K in keyof T]?: (keyof T)[]
  } = {}

  addVertex(value: keyof T) {
    if (!this.adjacencyList[value]) this.adjacencyList[value] = []
  }

  addEdge(vertex1: keyof T, vertex2: keyof T) {
    this.adjacencyList[vertex1]?.push(vertex2)
    this.adjacencyList[vertex2]?.push(vertex1)
  }
}
```

is there a more elegant way of doing it? I wanted to use generics in order to be more versatile. Is something like this possible?

```
enum Cities {
  "lisbon",
  "porto",
  "faro"
}

class Graph<T> {
  adjacencyList: {
    [K in T]?: T[]
  } = {}

  addVertex(value: T) {
    if (!this.adjacencyList[value]) this.adjacencyList[value] = []
  }

  addEdge(vertex1: T, vertex2: T) {
    this.adjacencyList[vertex1]?.push(vertex2)
    this.adjacencyList[vertex2]?.push(vertex1)
  }
}
```

says T is not assignable to type symbol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because typescript has no guarantee that all the values in `T` will actually be strings, numbers, or symbols (the only valid object keys as far as typescript is concerned). Think about what would happen if you fed `number[]` as `T`. So, add a clause that it has to extend `string | number | symbol`:

```js
class Graph<T extends string | number | symbol> {
  adjacencyList: {
    [K in T]?: T[]
  } = {}

  addVertex(value: T) {
    if (!this.adjacencyList[value]) this.adjacencyList[value] = []
  }

  addEdge(vertex1: T, vertex2: T) {
    this.adjacencyList[vertex1]?.push(vertex2)
    this.adjacencyList[vertex2]?.push(vertex1)
  }
}
```

Then, to feed an enum to it, use `keyof typeof Enum` to get the union type consisting of all possible strings:

```js
const foo = new Graph<keyof typeof Cities>();
```